# Baby Rudin Proof for Theorem 2.41 - help with first part

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Below is the first part of the proof. I cannot seem to visualise this out. What does $|{\bf x}_n|>n$ actually mean in a diagram?

> **2.41** $\ \ $ **Theorem** $\ \ $ *If a set $E$ in ${\bf R}^k$ has one of the following three properties, then it has the other two:*
>
> $\quad(a)\ \ $ *$E$ is closed and bounded.*
>   $\quad(b)\ \ $ *$E$ is compact*.
>   $\quad(c)\ \ $ *Every infinite subset of $E$ has a limit point in $E$.*
>
> **Proof** $\ \ $ If $(a)$ holds, then $E\subset I$ for some $k$-cell $I$, and $(b)$ follows from Theorems $2.40$ and $2.35$. Theorem $2.37$ shows that $(b)$ implies $(c)$. It remains to be shown that $(c)$ implies $(a)$.
>   $\qquad$ If $E$ is not bounded, then $E$ contains points ${\bf x}_n$ with $$|{\bf x}_n|>n\qquad(n=1,2,3,...).$$ The set $S$ consisting of these points ${\bf x}_n$ is infinite and clearly has no limit point in ${\bf R}^k$, hence has none in $E$. Thus $(c)$ implies that $E$ is bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radial distance of the point ${\bf x}_n$ from the origin is $> n$. This is what $|{\bf x}_n|>$ means.

Comment: Alright, thank you!